# How to change all CheckBoxes in a CustomListView from GONE to VISIBLE?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am trying to make a little FileExplorer. 
In the custom_list.xml I have defined a CheckBox (Visible = GONE), an image and 2 textViews. What I want is, that every CheckBoxes in the list change the visibility to View.VISIBLE when I do a LongItemClick.
I already tried it with getChildCount(). But the problem is, it works only on the drawed and doesn't when you are scrolling down.

So how can I show all of the CheckBoxes by doing a longclick on an item in the listview?

**customAdapter**

```
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(arrCurrentDirFolders, subheadListFolders, imgList, getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HERE I WANT TO SET VISIBILITY = VISIBLE FOR ALL CHECKBOXES 

            /*for(int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox_checkDir).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }*/

            return true;
        }
    });

    // set the list item on click listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(newAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

        Log.v("Position: ", position+" pressed");

        }
    });
```

**custom_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_checkDir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_customlist_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox_checkDir" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headingText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_customlist_icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_customlist_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subHeadingText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headingText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/headingText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: List all Elements from InternalStorage]
[image: LongClick on an Element]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easy just put a parameter called `isCheckBoxVisible` in the list object you pass to the adapter which will be false at first once you long press make for loop and update the list `isCheckBoxVisible` to true and then `notifydatasetchanged();` on the customadapter check for `isCheckBoxVisible` if true set checkbox to visible if false set checkbox to Gone